# Is it possible to debug an ad-hoc version of an iPhone app on iPhone using XCode?

Tags: iphone

I have an app that reads and writes data from sqlite3.  I tested it on the simulator it looks like everything is OK.  But if the ad-hoc version does a 'delete' or 'insert' query in the sqlite3 file on iPhone, it crashes.

Is it possible to debug ad hoc versions of iPhone apps with XCode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer is NO, you can't debug an AdHoc build on the iPhone.

AdHoc is a build configuration where the build had been signed with a publishing profile. In this case app will crashed when try to debug it. Please use 'debug' or 'release' configuration for debuging your app. The main requirement is that build should be signed with a development profile.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried testing a build on the device using a standard developer provisioning profile? It's a little hard to believe that the method of code signing is causing a crash.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the SQLite backing store located?

If it's located inside the app bundle, the writes will fail on the device (and will cause crashes depending on how you did the coding), but the app will work in the Simulator, since there's no true sandboxing.

Comment: Thanks

I copy the sqlite to sandbox

Comment: Okay -- so have you been testing development versions on a device, launched through Xcode?